# I don't understand why np.array is not multiply by y values in ODEint function? Giving error..as following

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-science, odeint

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import odeint

def flux(y,t):

   #constants

    L = Th231_LambdaAux (#array with 17 row)
    k1 = phi_1 (#contant)
    k2 = phi_2 (#contant)
    k3 = phi_3 (#contant)
    k4 = phi_4 (#contant)
    k5 = phi_5 (#contant)
    k6 = phi_6 (#contant)
    S1 = Th231_S_1 (#array with 17 row)
    S2 = Th231_S_2 (#array with 17 row)
    S3 = Th231_S_3 (#array with 17 row)
    S4 = Th231_S_4 (#array with 17 row)
    S5 = Th231_S_5 (#array with 17 row)
    S6 = Th231_S_6 (#array with 17 row) 

   #Fluxoutput

    fout1 = (1-0.9998)*y
    fout2 = 0.9998*y

   #differential equations

    dhdt1 = (L + ((k1*S1)+(k2*S2)+(k3*S3)+(k4*S4)+(k5*S5)+(k6*S6)))*fout1
    dhdt2 = (L + ((k1*S1)+(k2*S2)+(k3*S3)+(k4*S4)+(k5*S5)+(k6*S6)))*fout2
    dhdt = [dhdt1,dhdt2] 
    #or 
    #dhdt = np.add(dhdt1,dhdt2) (#also tried)
    return dhdt

# times to report solution

t = np.linspace(0,315360000) 

# initial conditions
y0 = 1 * 10 ** 22 
    
#or 

#y0 = [1 * 10 ** 22]  (#also tried)

# integrate
y = odeint(flux,y0,t)
```

[image]

```
# plot results

plt.figure(1)

plt.loglog(t,y[:,0],'b-')

plt.loglog(t,y[:,1],'r--')

plt.xlabel('Time (s)')

plt.ylabel('N [nuclide/cm3]')

plt.legend(['y1','y2'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: You provided a scalar initial condition `y0`, but your system of differential equations has more than one component.  The size of `y0` must match the size of the vectors returned by `flux(y, t)`.

Comment: Reread the error. It's not about multiplication.  Review `odeint` docs if necessary.